# Java Iterator is skipping elements

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, iterator

I noticed a strange behavior while debugging over a Iterator;the iterator skipped some elements. After a while, I realized ***debugging watchs are changing my runtime variables values.***

Then I'm getting

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:742) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

[image]
 2.

Comment: I see you call `planetsIterator.next()` to get a `pivot` and a `second` without checking `hasNext()`. This code is not a MCVE, but I would check you ***always*** invoke `hasNext()` before `next()`

Comment: What did you think a debug watch is doing? It's execute the expression so it can show you the result. If the expression is a `next()` call, then it calls `next()`. How is that surprising? --- Creating a watch for an expression with side-effects is a bad idea. Don't do it.

Comment: @cepix could you provide a whole working sample please (github link would be fine).

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the debug watchers.

This might help: from [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

> In access-ordered linked hash maps, merely querying the map with get is a structural modification

assuming you pass true for ordered access of the linkedhashmap constructor, your causing structural changes with every get operation.

your while

```
while(planetsIterator.hasNext() && ...) {
   Planet planet = planetsIterator.next();
   ...
}
```

gets compiled to

```
Iterator<Planet> it = planetsIterator.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String key = it.next();
    Planet planet = planetsIterator.get(key);
    ...
}
```

thus, the get operator causes structural changes.

You could work with the EntrySet to avoid this behavior.

Note that this implementation is not synchronized. Thus, its not thread-safe.